# ExtJS: Frequent XTemplate usage = performance hit?

Tags: extjs

I have an ExtJS Panel that displays several bits of data and needs to be updated frequently. For example, a panel that displays current market prices for the DOW, NYSE, NASDAQ, etc.

Considering that the data will be updated frequently (at least every second), **is it significantly more efficient to update individual elements for the data fields vs. re-generating all the HTML using an XTemplate each time?**

For example, if I *don't* reapply an XTemplate it might look like this:

```
update: function(marketData) {
   Ext.get('nasdaq-market-price-div-id').update(marketData.nasdaqPrice);
   Ext.get('nyse-market-price-div-id').update(marketData.nysePrice);
   //Repeat for all fields...
}
```

Compared to using an XTemplate each time, like this:

```
update: function(marketData) {
   var tpl = new XTemplate('<div>{nasdaqPrice}</div><div>{nysePrice}</div>');
   var html = tpl.applyTemplate(marketData);
   Ext.get('market-data-div-id').update(html);
}
```

I like using XTemplate because it allows me to separate the HTML (into a separate file, actually) and helps with code readability/maintainability. **However, does anyone know if there's a prohibitive performance hit by reapplying the template each time?** I'm guessing there is, but am hoping I can get an authoritative answer from someone "in the know."

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not authoritative at all, but I think you're likely to be optimizing prematurely.  The non-X-template method is likely somewhat less efficient, but do you have any reason to care?

Absent a description of some undesirable behavior, it sounds like you're worrying about a problem that doesn't exist now, and very likely will never exist in the future.

Keep your code clean until you have a real, present, reason to make it ugly for the sake of performance.

Comment: Thanks for the input--definitely valid points. In this case, the actual template is much more substantial (several lines of HTML, with at least 10 placeholders); my simplistic example was just meant to get the idea across. Assuming XTemplates work by doing some kind of search-and-replace operation, I was concerned that doing this on a really large string at least once every second might be drastically less efficient than just picking through the DOM and replacing individual elements. At any rate, really helpful to get your thoughts--thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with @timdev -- XTemplate should be fine (and is very fast BTW).  However, I would not create the XTemplate from scratch every time.  I'd do something more like this:

```
update: function(marketData) {
   // assuming that this is a class or some appropriate scope
   if(!this.PriceTpl){
       this.PriceTpl = new XTemplate('<div>{nasdaqPrice}</div><div>{nysePrice}</div>');
       this.PriceTpl.compile();
   }
   this.PriceTpl.overwrite('market-data-div-id', marketData);
}
```

Comment: +1 - I was going to put that in my answer as well, then forgot about it.

Comment: Good catch about re-instantiating the XTemplate obj each time; I'm not doing in my actual code (the example was meant to be super-simple) but the pointer is definitely appreciated.